# I can not access a text box with Selenium. Elements hid unless the text is clicked

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working in Python with Selenium. When I click on the line

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="page click-enterkey" style="text-align: center; margin: 0px 1em; float: left;">7</div>
```

and copy the path with a `click()` or then `send.keys(8)`, it will not go to page 8. It just flashes and keeps on moving to next line of code. But, as a human, if I click the box, it changes the elements to show that second picture with an input section.

What should I do?

```python
magicBox = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').click()
magicBox.send_keys('7')
magicBox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I also tried

```python
magicBox = driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="searchResults"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]').click().send_keys('7')
magicBox.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp1yZ.png)

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the relevant HTML and properly format it instead.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75305908/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML you provided, you are trying to `send_keys()` to a DIV which is not valid. My guess is that if you click the box that contains the "7" in your screenshot, an INPUT HTML element will appear in the DOM that you can `send_keys()` a new value to.

You might also check the URL and see if `?page=7` or something similar is there and you can just edit the URL to take you directly to the page you want.